# Pointer to function members: what does `R(*C::*)(Args...)` mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointer-to-member, member-functions

Consider the following code:

```
template <class>
struct test: std::integral_constant<int, 0> {};
template<class R, class C, class... Args>
struct test<R(C::*)(Args...)>: std::integral_constant<int, 1> {};
template<class R, class C, class... Args>
struct test<R(*C::*)(Args...)>: std::integral_constant<int, 2> {};
template<class R, class C, class... Args>
struct test<R(**C::*)(Args...)>: std::integral_constant<int, 3> {};
template<class R, class C, class... Args>
struct test<R(C::**)(Args...)>: std::integral_constant<int, 4> {};
template<class R, class C, class... Args>
struct test<R(C::***)(Args...)>: std::integral_constant<int, 5> {};
```

I have absolutely no idea of what `(*C::*)`, `(**C::*)`, `(C::**)` and `(C::***)` mean. I would like an example of a `test<decltype(f)>` whose `value` would be equal to `2`, `3`, `4` and `5`. Plus, in that case, how is the syntax for `f` that would call the member function?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Consider [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f01e8340bb40a7e2):

```
struct s {
    void test1();
    void(*test2)();
    void(**test3)();
};

int main() {
    static_assert(test<decltype(&s::test1)>::value == 1);   
    static_assert(test<decltype(&s::test2)>::value == 2);   
    static_assert(test<decltype(&s::test3)>::value == 3);   

    auto test4 = &s::test1;
    static_assert(test<decltype(&test4)>::value == 4);   

    auto test5 = &test4;
    static_assert(test<decltype(&test5)>::value == 5);   
}
```

Here are the types:

`R(C::*)(Args...)` - A pointer to a member function.
`R(*C::*)(Args...)` - A pointer to a data member that is a function pointer.
`R(**C::*)(Args...)` - A pointer to a data member that is a pointer to a function pointer.
`R(C::**)(Args...)` - A pointer to a pointer to a member function.
`R(C::***)(Args...)` - A pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a member function.

To call these, consider a [slightly modified example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b30fd971178194b):

```
struct s {
    void test1() {std::cout << "test1\n";}
    void(*test2)() = [] {std::cout << "test2\n";};

    void(*test3Helper)() = [] {std::cout << "test3\n";};
    void(**test3)() = &test3Helper;

    void test4() {std::cout << "test4\n";}
    void test5() {std::cout << "test5\n";}
};

int main() {
    s obj;  

    auto test4 = &s::test4;

    auto test5Helper = &s::test5;
    auto test5 = &test5Helper;  

    (obj.*(&s::test1))();
    (*(obj.*(&s::test2)))(); // note that the dereference is unnecessary
    (**(obj.*(&s::test3)))(); // note that the second dereference is unnecessary
    (obj.**(&test4))();
    (obj.***(&test5))();
}
```

Note that in each case, if you have a variable with the value of the appropriate `&[s::]testN`, you can replace `(&[s::]testN)` with that variable. Note also that for test2 and test3, I dereferenced until getting the function back rather than the function pointer for illustration purposes.

Comment: Thanks! Could you give an example if `s` has a function member `int f(int x) {return x;}`, and `testN` refers to it, what is the syntax to execute `testN` on a variable?

Comment: @Vincent, I was getting to that. One second.